# How to pass multiple parameters in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i am trying to execute like exec print_emp(1010,1111) but it will showing error.

```
create or replace 
procedure print_emp(
    P_empno NUMBER 
)
IS
begin
 for c in ( SELECT *
  from emp
  where empno in p_empno)
  loop
  dbms_output.put_line( c.empno||' '||c.ename||' '||c.job||' '||c.sal);
end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a type that is a collection of numbers, and then a procedure that accepts that collection.

Rather than use the IN operator, you should use MEMBER OF to test whether a scalar value is in a collection.

```
create or replace type tab_number is table of number
/

create or replace procedure print_nums 
 (p_nums in tab_number) 
is
  cursor c_main is
  select column_value
  from table(p_nums)
  order by 1;
begin
  for r_main in c_main loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r_main.column_value);
  end loop;
  --
  if 33 member of p_nums then
    dbms_output.put_line('In the list');
  end if;
end;
/

exec print_nums(tab_number(10,20,50));

exec print_nums(tab_number(10,20,33));
```

Comment: still i am getting error because i need different types of data, i have to put multiple empid and it will fetch all data

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, if all parameters you'd like to pass represent the same column value, you can't just *list* them as if they were two **different** parameters. If that was the case, procedure should actually name them all, e.g.

```
create procedure print_emp(par_emp_1 in number, par_emp_2 in number)
```

but - what if there are 3 or 4 `EMPNO`s you'd like to pass? You can't modify the procedure every time (not just while *declaring* it, but also in `SELECT` statements, as you'd have to add new parameters there as well).

---

Therefore, one option might be this (as far as I understood the question):

- one parameter, whose datatype is `varchar2`

  - it means that you'd have to enclose list of `EMPNO`s into single quotes and separate them with the same separator every time; let it be a comma `,` sign
- cursor's query would contain a subquery (lines #6 - 9) which splits that comma-separated values list of `EMPNO` values into rows
- the rest is simple

Here you go:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure print_emp(par_empno in varchar2)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    for c in (select *
  5              from emp
  6              where empno in (select to_number(regexp_substr(par_empno, '[^,]+', 1, level))
  7                              from dual
  8                              connect by level <= regexp_count(par_empno, ',') + 1
  9                             )
 10             )
 11    loop
 12      dbms_output.put_line(c.empno||' '||c.ename||' '||c.job||' '||c.sal);
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

Scott's `EMP` sample table:

```
SQL> select * from emp where deptno = 20;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.1980 00:00:00       1000                    20
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.1981 00:00:00       2975                    20
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.1982 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.1983 00:00:00       1100                    20
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.1981 00:00:00       3000                    20
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec print_emp('7369,7566,7788');
7566 JONES MANAGER 2975
7788 SCOTT ANALYST 3000
7369 SMITH CLERK 1000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```